# Give Dynamic SKSpriteNode a fixed X position

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have nodes moving right to left and another node that sits on top as they move.

it does not allow rotation and when the user swipes up the ball moves up. however, after an extended amount of time the node starts to move to the left. i have set the restitution to 0.0 so that there is less movement from bouncing.

I am trying to come up with the best way to fix the top nodes x position so it can only move in one dimension, along the y axis

thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override node's `setPosition:` and `setFrame:` methods and always set the `x` value to the desired one.